# Copy code to clipboard on build in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an unusual situation here.

### Problem

I'm using Visual studio (VS) to write scripts to use [in-game in the game Space Engineers](http://www.spaceengineerswiki.com/Programmable_Block).

The problem is that you only use a portion of the code from the file in-game. (I.E, Ctrl+A wont do). So selecting the correct portion is tedious.

I want to streamline the process of copying the desired code in VS and pasting it in Space Engineers.
The idea is to trim all unnecessary white space (there's a character limit) and copy to clipboard when pressing run in VS.

### Where I'm at

I've found that you can make your own build configuration and use the "Pre-build event command line" to run something custom. The idea is to make a simple console application that does what I described above. But I don't know how to get the correct file to send to said application.

Am I on the right track? How do I send the desired file to the trimming application? Is there a better way?

---

**Edit:**
This is what I had in mind when I said "simple console application".
It does everything I needed it to do (trimming white-space and adding a portion of the code to clipboard). Only thing missing is that I have to specify the file name I want it to use. Which isn't important, it would just be nice.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TrimFileToClipboard
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startString = (args.Length > 1) ? "#region " + args[1] : "#region in-game";
            string line;
            string trimmed = "";
            bool read = false;
            int depth = 0;

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(args[0]);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!read && line.Contains(startString)) read = true;
                else if (read && line.Contains("#region")) depth++;
                else if (read && line.Contains("#endregion"))
                {
                    if (depth == 0) break;
                    else if (depth < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There's something wrong with your #regions. Please edit the file.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    else depth--;
                }
                else if (read) trimmed += line.Trim() + "\n";
            }
            file.Close();

            Clipboard.SetText(trimmed);
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used by adding 
`"<path>\TrimFileToClipboard.exe" "$(ProjectDir)<classname>.cs"`
to Pre-build event command line, in the project properties/Build events. Where `<path>` is the path to the application above and `<classname>` is the file you want to process.

Maybe I should post this part as an answer but I don't know if it's a decent approach or an ugly hack.

Comment: "The idea is to make a simple console application" definitely not, with what you described.  You could learn how to make a Visual Studio extension, which will take a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I agree, this application isn't "simple".  "But I don't know how to get the correct file to send to said application."  What about providing the filename as a command-line argument?

Comment: You can pass arguments to build events. Identify the file with a path relative to `$(ProjectDir)` or whatever -- there's a bunch of "macros" like that. The post-build command is interpreted as a batch file. Write a script that takes the file as a command line parameter and copies the required part to the clipboard. Identifiying the part you want to copy may be hard, unless you can just sandwich it between magic comments. Then it's easy. Am I missing something? This doesn't seem like a real big deal to me.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The $(ProjectDir) looks great! What I need then is the file name of the currently active file. Unless I hardcode that part, but that wouldn't be very flexible.

Comment: Whoops, I *was* missing something. I don't think VS build has any concept of "active file" (what for?) -- unless you want one project per script file, which seems clumsy. One possibility is to write a console application that [monitors the directory where you save your scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx), and when a file is saved, it does the copy-whatever-part-to-clipboard thing. No need to get VS involved I don't think. But if you save constantly while coding, that would be a problem.

Comment: Another option might be [a VS macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(v=vs.100).aspx). I think those are VBS, which can use the RegExp object

Comment: @EdPlunkett I do save constantly. I guess I'll have to give up on having it automatically know what file is relevant and add that manually to the build commands (Like this: "$(ProjectDir)MyClass.cs"). Because that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a C# command with my Visual Commander extension that gets active file path in Visual Studio as DTE.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName and then runs your file.ReadLine() loop over it and calls Clipboard.SetText(trimmed) at the end. See for example [Copy current file, line, method](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#CopyCurrentLine) sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coping the code to the clipboard, I save it directly inside the game as saved workshop script with this simple C# console application.

The SE script I edit using VS has the comments `\\script-begin` and `\\script-end` to tell the application where to look for the actual code that needs to be in the programmable block.

After the execution the script will be available at the local workshop. It makes it very easy to work with the SE scripts, whenever I make a change using VS, I run the console application again and the script will be updated inside the game.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] InputLines, outputLines;
        Int32 scriptBegin = 0, scriptEnd = 0;

        String scriptName = args[0];
        String inputPath = "C:\\Users\\hfand\\source\\repos\\se-scripts\\" + scriptName + ".cs";

        if (File.Exists(inputPath))
        {
            InputLines = File.ReadAllLines(inputPath);

            for (int i = 0; i < InputLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (InputLines[i].Contains("script-begin"))
                {
                    scriptBegin = i + 1;
                }
                if (InputLines[i].Contains("script-end"))
                {
                    scriptEnd = i - 1;
                }
            }

            outputLines = new List<string>(InputLines).GetRange(scriptBegin, scriptEnd - scriptBegin + 1).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < outputLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (outputLines[i].Length >= 8)
                {
                    outputLines[i] = outputLines[i].Substring(8);
                }
            }

            String outputPath = "C:\\Users\\hfand\\AppData\\Roaming\\SpaceEngineers\\IngameScripts\\local\\" + scriptName;

            if (Directory.Exists(outputPath))
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(outputPath + "\\Script.cs", outputLines);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
                File.WriteAllLines(outputPath + "\\Script.cs", outputLines);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(scriptName + " sincronizado");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arquivo \"" + inputPath + "\" não encontrado");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how the code in VS should look like

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using VRageMath;
using VRage.Game;
using Sandbox.ModAPI.Interfaces;
using Sandbox.ModAPI.Ingame;
using Sandbox.Game.EntityComponents;
using VRage.Game.Components;
using VRage.Collections;
using VRage.Game.ObjectBuilders.Definitions;
using VRage.Game.ModAPI.Ingame;
using SpaceEngineers.Game.ModAPI.Ingame;

namespace BlankScript
{
    public class Program : MyGridProgram
    {
        //script-begin
        public Program()
        {
        }

        public void Save()
        { 
        }

        public void Main(string argument, UpdateType updateSource)
        {
        }
        //script-end
    }
}
```